# Earth goes out of orbit in java simulation

Tags: simulation

Firstly I'm very new to java, apologies. I'm trying to simulate the Earth going around the sun. After plotting the results, its apparent the Earth spirals out of orbit just after one revolution!

I've checked and double checked the constants such as the mass of the sun and the Earth as well as the initial velocity and position. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong the equations are also correct confirmed by colleagues and the lecturer.

Code consists of 4 classes:

find.

Comment: The final class is the vector class I'm certain the error is not present in there.

Comment: Ask yourself what happens every time you do 'timestep' or every time your simulation approximates calculations numerically.

Comment: You're estimating future position using discrete steps, and mathematically you're doing this using a first order approximation when you would likely need a higher order approximation (of the Taylor or MacLaurin series). I'm not sure of the most efficient way to do this in code though.

Comment: Numbers you are using are all over the scale. Floating point math is not working well for such cases. For anything involving such wide range of values, you should use some more exact numeric representation with well defined error boundaries. Rewrite it all using BigDecimal, pick proper rounding levels (this might be non-obvious step) and you should get better results.

Comment: Is this an assignment? If so, it's possibly the point of the assignment to demonstrate the limitations of this modelling approach...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bad:**

```
y += yVelocity * timeStep;     
x += xVelocity * timeStep;
```

As you are using discrete timesteps, you must not only add the velocity to your position, but also the effect that acceleration will have on your velocity during that time.

**Better:**

```
yAccel = Sun.componentY();     
xAccel = Sun.componentX();

y += (yVelocity + yAccel * timeStep * 0.5) * timeStep;
x += (xVelocity + xAccel * timeStep * 0.5) * timeStep;

yVelocity += yAccel * timeStep;
xVelocity += xAccel * timeStep;
```

This assumes the acceleration to remain constant throughout the duration of the timestep, which in reality it doesn't. Still, it should get much closer to the goal you want to achieve.

**Best:**

Using integrals you should be able to model the real behaviour perfectly (ignoring floating point issues).

Acceleration, velocity and position can all be expressed using integrals, which then you should be able to solve for the per-frame simulation range of t to t+dt. I've found that a trial license of Mathematica can be very helpful in such situations.

Comment: Thanks,. I've just tried this, your right it does get closer however the Earth still goes out of orbit. Did you mean  y+= (yVelocity +(yAccel*timestep*0.5))*timestep ?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Should come to the same thing however.

Comment: This approach in calculation assumes that acceleration stays constant during the duration of timestep, which, in reality, it doesn't. Thus the result can not be exact, but will get better with smaller timesteps. You can try to simulate acceleration changes during timestep as well, which will get you even closer, but it won't ever be perfect I suppose.